# Configure VS 2010 Help for a specific subject

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Using VS2008, you could set Document Explorer to limit your search to specific subjects using the Technology dropdown, which made for finding info on a specific subject very easy, as it was limited to a subset of available subject. How is the accomplished in the new VS2010 help?

The VS2010 help at the moment, is very hazy. When I search for Task, or task, or c# task.  re the new Task library in .net, it returns a whole bundle of irrelevancy...

Any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the Document Explorer is not compatible with VS 2010.  There is an extension called [H3Viewer](http://mshcmigrate.helpmvp.com/viewer) developed by a third party which apparently provides similar functionality.

Info stolen from here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3449925/Re-VS2010-documentation-in.aspx